# How can I load/Read images in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm trying to load image in Java but I'm facing this error:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

This is my code:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    private static BufferedImage tmp;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
             tmp = ImageIO.read(new File("defaults.png"));
            System.out.println("reading completed ");
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error loading image ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the full complete exception message you get or have you cut any part of the error message?

Comment: i had cut the  **System.out.println** with message **saying Error loading image** only
so it the full complete exception

Comment: Well I would say either 1) the file doesn't exist or 2) it is not an image file.

Comment: Does the file exist? Can you open it in an image viewer? Do you have permission to read the file?

Comment: 1) I'm pretty sure the path is correct even i putted the image in same level with java class 
2) i tried different images 
3) I also tried to change image permission and gives to all user rwx

Comment: Note that according to the code you posted, java will look for file `defaults.png` in the working directory which is the value returned by `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

Comment: Given the image name is coded in the source, it seems this image is an application resource and thus must be read as an **embedded resource** (IE from a Jar or class-path using an URL). What will the code be doing with the image once successfully loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like this, I would suggest:

- Log out the absolute path of the file, to check that the system is looking for it where you think it is looking for it
- Try to read the file with one of the newer file API calls (available via the Files class) which will tend to give more clueful errors us to why the file cannot be read:

  ```
    File f = new File("defaults.png");
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        Path p = f.toPath();
        Files.readAllBytes(p);
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This specific error message is thrown when, well, the file can't be read. Check the source code of [`ImageIO.read()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/9d617cfd6717/src/share/classes/javax/imageio/ImageIO.java#l1300):

> ```
> if (!input.canRead()) {
>     throw new IIOException("Can't read input file!");
> }
> ```

It uses the [`File.canRead()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead()) method to check if the file can be read. The documentation from that method say:

> **Returns:**
>
> `true` if and only if the file specified by this abstract pathname exists *and* can be read by the application; `false` otherwise

So the file you are trying to load must exists and the permission must be correct. When the [`exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) method returns `false` for your `File` object you know that the file you are trying to load does not exists (in the working directory you are in). When the file does indeed exists, it is a permission issue that your application are not allowed to read the file.